# ServiceLoader + EJB injection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x, serviceloader

I would like to know if I can combine the `ServiceLoader` with EJB and injection from Java EE 6.

Imagine I have an interface `ServiceI` that can be implemented by two EJB stateless beans `BeanA` and `BeanB`.

If I register these two classes in the `MEAT-INF/services` they will be instantiated in the Java SE way, rather than being managed by the Application Container (like when you use `@Inject`). This means that annotations like `@Inject` or `@PostConstruct` won't be resolved.

Is it possible to have something like a `ServiceLoader` which would allow me to go through EJB beans implementing a given interface and returning one based on some criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

If both beans implements the `Service` interface you can do the following:

```
@Inject
private javax.enterprise.inject.Instance.Instance<Service> services
```

`services` implements `Iterator<Service>` and will allow to cycle through all the beans that implement the `Service` interface.

Then you can choose one of the implementations based on some criteria and you have the equivalent of `ServiceLoader` for EJB!